# How to delete a project in rallydev

Tags: alm

I'm using the community edition of RallyDev, so I accept that I have limited functionality.

It's quite clear I am limited to 1 workspace, and 10 team members. But it doesn't say anything about the number of projects allowed.

I need to create a new project.

I'm quite happy to delete the existing project, or create a new one, whatever does the trick. I'm even happy to delete the workspace containing the project, and start afresh. Hell, I'll even delete my account and start over if necessary.

But for the life of me, I cannot find any way to do it. All I get is messages that "You cannot delete the workspace with an open project" / "You cannot close the last open project"

And there is no function I can find, either in the app or the documentation that explains how to start a new project.

I've logged a case with RallyDev, but I'm not sure I'll get an answer due to the low priority of my request.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite impressed with RallyDev's response... contrary to my expectations, my query got a response within 12 hours saying that

- Community edition accounts cannot create or delete projects.
- The only options are to:

  - Upgrade to enterprise edition, or
  - cleanout existing artifacts and recreate, or
  - create a new trial account.

(The online support documentation does not explain this).

Hope it helps someone.